# .NET Regex Expression to parse File with delimeters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I do have to parse files with the following sample structure

```
// This is a comment
  // NotUsed : 123654

****************************************
*          DESCRIPTION
***************************************
Header:         xxx
Date:           20010101    
ReqDate:20150402
P.O.            123456
Qty         10000
Part Number:     xx-yy-456
Type:           J
Product:            xxyy123456V0.01 (bulk) 
Cust ID:    51
Model:          
Location:       60
UPC:            123456
*
cust_ref:       Hello Worlkd
*
***************************************
*          Data
***************************************
```

I did try to use the following Regex, but it is not capturing the Key / Value when the colon (:) is not used

```
public class TestRegEx
{
    private static readonly Regex KeyValFileRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?<key>(?!:)[\w\.]+|[ \w\.]+)\s*[\s=:]\s*(?<value>[^\n]*)(?=[^()\n]*[ =:\(]?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputStr = @"// This is a comment
  // NotUsed : 123654

****************************************
*          DESCRIPTION
***************************************
Header:         xxx
Date:           20010101    
ReqDate:20150402
P.O.            123456
Qty         10000
Part Number:     xx-yy-456
Type:           J
Product:            xxyy123456V0.01 (bulk) 
Cust ID:    51
Model:          
Location:       60
UPC:            123456
*
cust_ref:       Hello Worlkd
*
***************************************
*          Data
***************************************";

        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputStr));

        using (var r = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var data = new Data();
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var match = KeyValFileRegex.Match(line);

                if (!match.Success) continue;

                var key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
                var value = match.Groups["value"].Value;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) value = value.Trim();

                switch (key)
                {
                    case "Header":
                        data.Header = value;
                        break;
                    case "ReqDate":
                        data.RequestedDeliveryDate = value;
                        break;
                    case "Qty":
                        data.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                        break;
                    case "Type":
                        data.Type = value;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private class Data
    {
        public string Header { set; get; }
        public string RequestedDeliveryDate { set; get; }
        public string Brand { set; get; }
        public string Po { set; get; }
        public int Qty { set; get; }
        public string Type { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Any Help will be very appreciated.

Comment: so if a colon is not there, what would you use to determine the different fields?

Comment: Have you considered just writing code to parse this?  For each line check for `//` and `*` or blank lines to skip.  Everything else look for a colon to split on, or if there is no colon split on the first space.  If no space skip.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex is flawed, the "Cust ID" field is returned with "Cust" as a key and the rest of it as value. Reason for that is the `[\s=:]` part of the regex. It is configured to use both space and colon character as a delimiter.

So, even with the current set of delimiters you have a problem. Now, you can put anything else in those brackets but the more delimiters you add to it all the more problems you will have. It seems that you're not sure what kind of data format to expect.

Generally you should configure regex to accept **either one** of delimiters rather than trying all of them in the same script. This is done by attempting to parse with one script and if no results are given, try another script. Of course, this is bad practice but if you're working with unpredictable data it's the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another approach: if there is a colon, match any number of spaces, and if not, match at least 3 spaces - and use that match to split the string. Have a look:

```
public int Start()
{
    var rxDelim = new Regex(@"(?(:):\s*|\s{3,})\s*");
    var inputStr = @"// This is a comment
                 // NotUsed : 123654

****************************************
*          DESCRIPTION
***************************************
Header:         xxx
Date:           20010101    
ReqDate:20150402
P.O.            123456
Qty         10000
Part Number:     xx-yy-456
Type:           J
Product:            xxyy123456V0.01 (bulk) 
Cust ID:    51
Model:          
Location:       60
UPC:            123456
*
cust_ref:       Hello Worlkd
*
***************************************
*          Data
***************************************";

var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputStr));
var line = string.Empty;
using (var r = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var data = new Data();
    var s = string.Empty;
    while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(?i)^\*[^\r\n]*Description"))
        {
           s = r.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
           line += s;
           var add = r.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
           while (add != null && !Regex.IsMatch(add, @"(?i)^\*[^\r\n]*Description"))
           {
               line += add + "\r\n";
               add = r.ReadLine();
           }
           var matches = line.Split(new[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(p => rxDelim.Split(p).GetLength(0) > 1 && rxDelim.Split(p)[0] != "*" && !rxDelim.Split(p)[0].TrimStart(new[] { ' ' }).StartsWith("//") ?
                   new { Key = rxDelim.Split(p)[0], Value = rxDelim.Split(p)[1] } :
                   new { Key = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty });
           foreach (var v in matches)
           {
               if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v.Key) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v.Value))
               {
                   switch (v.Key)
                   {
                      case "Header":
                           data.Header = v.Value;
                           break;
                      case "ReqDate":
                           data.RequestedDeliveryDate = v.Value;
                           break;
                      case "Qty":
                           data.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(v.Value);
                           break;
                      case "Type":
                           data.Type = v.Value;
                           break;
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer do the trick with minor modif: the indexes you used ([1] & [2]) are not the capturing group, you should use ([2] & [3]) , and do check on the length of the split (size > 2).

Comment: I just ran your code as-is, and all of the keys on the Dict are empty strings, I assume that the first match is empty on every hit. I will check it again.. thx

Comment: I think I finally got it. You can read in the string by line, get the Description section, then parse using regex, and populate the required Data object fields. You can add more field support to meet your requirements.